# nokogiri nodeset shows all nodes from document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I'm selecting a nodeset according to some condition. The resulting nodeset is correct. But if I do an xpath on it I get all the nodes from the document. I must be missing something here. Explanation and solution would be appreciated.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(DATA)

selection = doc.xpath("//listing[code[contains(text(), '34')]]")

p selection.length   ## 2 
p selection.xpath("//id").inner_text  ##34567 (ids of all nodes), I'm trying to get 35 instead

__END__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listings>
  <listing>
    <id>3</id>
    <code>3,4,55,34</code>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <id>4</id>
    <code>3,4,55,33</code>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <id>5</id>
    <code>3,4,55,34</code>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <id>6</id>
    <code>3,4,55</code>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <id>7</id>
    <code>3,14</code>
  </listing>
</listings>
```

Comment: Use `.//` if you want relative to a node. Also selection is a nodeset not a node.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But why would `selection` still have access to `doc` here? I assumed it would only have nodes 3 and 5.

Comment: Because `//` means anywhere from the doc root.